# endpoints-proto-datastore: How to ignore required fields in EndpointsAliasProperty setters?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, endpoints-proto-datastore

I've got two classes: GameSession and Location. Each GameSession shall have got a Location set.

```
class Location(EndpointsModel):
    _message_fields_schema = ('entityKey', 'name', 'description', 'address')

    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.TextProperty()
    address = ndb.StringProperty()


class GameSession(EndpointsModel):
    _message_fields_schema = ('entityKey', 'name', 'description', 'location')

    name = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    description = ndb.TextProperty()
    location_key = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Location, required=True)

    def location_setter(self, value):
        self.location_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=value.entityKey)

    @EndpointsAliasProperty(setter=location_setter, property_type=Location.ProtoModel())
    def location(self):
        return self.location_key.get()
```

When I try to create a new GameSession through Google's API Explorer I get the following error message:

```
Error parsing ProtoRPC request (Unable to parse request content: Message Location is missing required field name)
```

The POST request to gamesession looks like the following:

```
{
 "name": "aaa",
 "location": {
  "entityKey": "ahRkZXZ-Z2FtZXNlc3Npb24tY29yZXIVCxIITG9jYXRpb24YgICAgIDArwoM"
 }
}
```

How can I create a GameSession entry with just having to specify the entityKey of the location? I do just want to store the key, that's why I do not want to ask for name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with:

```
 _message_fields_schema = ('entityKey', 'name', 'description', 'location')
```

specifically 'entityKey' should not be there.  You can mask your keys with something like this

```
def IdSet(self, value):
    if not isinstance(value, basestring):
        raise TypeError('ID must be a string.')
    self.UpdateFromKey(ndb.Key(Location, value))

@EndpointsAliasProperty(setter=IdSet, required=True)
def game_session(self):
    if self.key is not None:
        return self.key.string_id()
```

Then change _message_fields_schema to:

```
_message_fields_schema = ('name', 'description', 'game_session', 'address')
```

where game_session will set and get the ID of the game by key